# MVC AS3 Error: Call to a possibly undefined method through a reference with static type

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller

I'm new to AS3 from Java and was trying to implement a Java style as3 mvc implementation which essentially has two views with an input field and text box which has it's contents changed by buttons.
I keep getting Error: Call to a possibly undefined method handleMouseClick through a reference with static type controller:Controller. and can't understand why. This is for the function handleMouseClick in TextToolsView

Here is my code (sorry for it being so long, I'm not sure how to condense it further without losing my error):

TextModel

```
package model 
{
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

public class TextModel extends EventDispatcher
{
    private var text:String = new String();
    private var initialText:String = new String("Initial Text");

    public function TextModel() 
    {
        setText(initialText);
    }
    public function setText(text:String):void {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public function getText():String {
        return this.text;
    }

    public function updateText(text:String):void {
        setText(text);
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
    }

    public function clearText():void {
        setText("Text has been cleared");
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
    }

    public function resetText():void {
        setText(initialText);
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
    }
}
}
```

TextController

```
package controller 
{
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import model.TextModel;

public class TextController extends AbstractController 
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param   m   model to modify
     */
    public function TextController(m:TextModel) 
    {
        super(m);

    }
    private function updateText(text:String):void {
        TextModel(getModel()).updateText(text);
    }

    private function clearText():void {
        TextModel(getModel()).clearText();
    }

    private function resetText():void {
        TextModel(getModel()).resetText();
    }


    /*override public function update(obj: Object) {

    }*/

    public function handleMouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        switch(event.currentTarget.id) {
            case "_updateButton":
            updateText("TEXT INPUT TO BE ADDED LATER");//add text input later   
            break;

            case "_clearButton":
            clearText();
            break;

            case "_resetButton":
            resetText();
            break;

        }
    }
}
}
```

AbstractController

```
package controller 
{
import model.TextModel;
import view.View;
/**
 * Provides basic services for the "controller" of
 * a Model/View/Controller triad.
 *
 */
public class AbstractController
{
    private var model:TextModel;
    private var view:View;

    public function AbstractController(m:TextModel) 
    {
        setModel(m);
    }

    public function setModel(m:TextModel):void 
    {
        model = m;
    }

    public function getModel():TextModel 
    {
        return model;
    }

    public function setView(v:View):void 
    {
        view = v;
    }

    public function getView():View 
    {
        return view;
    }

    public function update(obj:Object):void {

    }
}

}
```

TextBoxView

```
package view 
{
import controller.Controller;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import model.TextModel;
import model.TextUpdate;

/**
 * ...
 */
public class TextBoxView extends AbstractView {
    private var wrapper:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var textBox:TextField = new TextField();
    private var inputField:TextField = new TextField();

    public function TextBoxView(m:TextModel, c:Controller, x:int, y:int) {
        super(m, c);

        textBox.text = "This is a text Panel with lots of text!!!!!!!!!!!!dghsdfghdfghdfghdfghdfghdfghdfghdfghdfghdfghdfghdfghdfgh";
        textBox.border = true;
        textBox.borderColor = 0x000000;
        textBox.multiline = true;
        textBox.width = 425;
        textBox.height = 115;
        textBox.x = 145;
        textBox.y = 20;
        textBox.wordWrap = true;

        var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
        myFormat.color = 0xAA0000;    
        myFormat.size = 24;    
        myFormat.italic = true;     
        //myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER
        textBox.setTextFormat(myFormat); 

        addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, this.update);


        //inputable text box
        inputField.border = true;
        inputField.width = 200;
        inputField.height = 150;
        inputField.x = 200;
        inputField.y = 50;
        inputField.type = "input";
        inputField.multiline = true;

        wrapper.addChild(textBox);
        wrapper.addChild(inputField);
        addChild(wrapper);
}

    public function update(event:Event):void {
        textBox.text = super.getModel().getText();
    }

}

}
```

TextToolsView

```
package view 
{
import controller.Controller;
import flash.events.Event
import controller.TextController;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import model.TextModel;
import model.TextUpdate;
import ui.CustomButton;

public class TextToolsView extends AbstractView 
{
    private var updateButton:CustomButton;
    private var clearButton:CustomButton;
    private var resetButton:CustomButton;
    private var wrapper:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var textModel:TextModel;
    private var textController:TextController;

    public function TextToolsView(m:TextModel, c:Controller, x:int, y:int) {
        super(m, c);
        makeTools(x, y);
    }

    override public function defaultController (model:TextModel):Controller {
        return new TextController(model);
    }

    private function makeTools(x:int, y:int):void {
        updateButton = new CustomButton("update", "_updateButton", 100, 22); 
        updateButton.x = 0;
        updateButton.y = 0;
        updateButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMouseClick);          

        clearButton = new CustomButton("clear", "_clearButton", 100, 22); 
        clearButton.x = 120;
        clearButton.y = 0;
        clearButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMouseClick);

        resetButton = new CustomButton("reset", "_resetButton", 100, 22); 
        resetButton.x = 240;
        resetButton.y = 0;
        resetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMouseClick);

        wrapper.x = x;
        wrapper.y = y;
        wrapper.addChild(updateButton);
        wrapper.addChild(clearButton);
        wrapper.addChild(resetButton);
        addChild(wrapper);
    }

    private function handleMouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
            super.getController().handleMouseClick(event);  
    }
}

}
```

Abstract View

```
package view 
{
import controller.Controller;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import model.TextModel;

/**
* Provides basic services for the "view" of
* a Model/View/Controller triad.
*/
public class AbstractView extends Sprite 

{
    private var model:TextModel;
    private var controller:Controller;

    public function AbstractView(m:TextModel, c:Controller) 
    {
        setModel(m);
        setController(c);
    }

    /** 
     * returns the default controller for this view
     */
    public function defaultController (model:TextModel):Controller {
        return null;
    }
    /**
      * Sets the model this view is observing.
      */
    public function setModel (m:TextModel):void {
        model = m;
    }

    /**
    * Returns the model this view is observing.
    */
    public function getModel ():TextModel {
        return model;
    }

    /**
    * Sets the controller for this view.
    */
    public function setController (c:Controller):void {
        controller = c;
        // Tell the controller this object is its view.
        getController().setView(this);

    }

    /**
    * Returns this view's controller.
    */
    public function getController():Controller {
        return controller;
    }


}

}
```

I won't post the custom button because essentially it works fine like any normal button.

and Main

```
package 
{
import controller.TextController;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import model.TextModel;
import view.TextBoxView;
import view.TextToolsView;

/**
 * ...
 */
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    private var text_model:TextModel;
    private var text_box:TextBoxView;
    private var text_tools:TextToolsView;
    private var textController:TextController;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point

        text_model = new TextModel();
        textController = new TextController(text_model);

        text_box = new TextBoxView(text_model, textController, 0,0);
        //text_model.addObserver(text_box);
        text_tools = new TextToolsView(text_model, textController, 120, 300);
        //text_model.addObserver(text_tools);
        addChild(text_box);
        addChild(text_tools);


    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see code of `Controller`, but I think problem is linked to it.

```
super.getController().handleMouseClick(event);
```

In this code getController() method returns Controller instance, but this class doesn't contain method `handleMouseClick()`. So, I think, you need to cast Controller to TextController like this:

```
(getController() as TextController).handleMouseClick(event);
```